# GPS coordinates display at UART in Degree minutes seconds format

Tags: c, uart, gps

I am receiving coordinates from my GPS module like mentioned on below.

```
uint8_t *latPtr = tmpPtr + 1;
```

when I am writing latPtr value in UART I can view lat value in terminal.

```
uartwrite(latPtr); // output is 1257.4370N
```

Find my uartwrite function on below

```
void uartwrite( char *data)  
{
  while(*data)
  {
    EUSART_Write(*data);
    *data++;   
  }
}
```

Now I want to convert the  lat value in to degree minutes seconds format.
So that I have written below mentioned code on my main file

```
float res1=*lonPtr;

float flo=res1/100;
int ilong=flo;

float lati=flo-ilong;
float res1=lati*60;
int minutes=res1;
uartwrite(minutes);

float isec=res1-minutes;
int lasec=isec*60;     
uartwrite(lasec);
uartwrite("\n\r");
```

how to send DMS to UART?

Comment: This output, what format is this?

Comment: Apparently you have a pointer to a *string*. You must convert that string to a (floating point) numerical type ("atof"), do your calculations, and convert the results back to a string for output. "float res1=*lonPtr;" won't do.

Comment: I have used atof ( float res1=atof(data);) and its working